# Does JDBC driver do automatic type casting for Postgres

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc

My question was based on an observation that I made and couldn't find an answer.

In my java code, I have inserted a value of type "Double" into the table using the normal statement.setDouble(number) and retrieval of the same value using the normal resultSet.getDouble();

However the in the said table this particular column is of type 'Text'

How is it that the value is getting inserted and retrieved? Is Postgres / driver converting it? Shouldn't it be throwing an error instead due to data type mismatch?

Also if Postgres / driver is auto-casting it how does it affect performance?
Using Postgres 9.4

So this just an observation more like learning from a trial. I know its definitely not what I would write as standard code.

Comment: The real question is: why on earth are you storing numbers in a `text` column?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, the driver is doing conversions. In `PGResultSet` class you can find the code used for conversion (this is called if the column is text, for binary columns there are other conversions).

```
public static double toDouble(String s) throws SQLException {
    if (s != null) {
      try {
        s = s.trim();
        return Double.parseDouble(s);
      } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        throw new PSQLException(GT.tr("Bad value for type {0} : {1}", new Object[]{"double", s}),
            PSQLState.NUMERIC_VALUE_OUT_OF_RANGE);
      }
    }
    return 0; // SQL NULL
}
```

The specification states that such conversions should be made, so it's working according to the spec. Whether you should rely on those conversions is a different matter, as `a_horse_with_no_name` commented, why **are** you storing doubles as text?

Performance has nothing to do with this. Compared to the things the driver is really doing (i.e. reading and writing data), doing conversions is a drop in the ocean.

Default conversions dictated by the JDBC spec can be found from appendix `B.6` at the end of 
http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/jdbc-4_3-mrel3-eval-spec/jdbc4.3-fr-spec.pdf

Comment: Thanks, a little new to this. Can I know a little more about this specification that you were mentioning? And the same goes with the insertion as well right?

Comment: @Vpm added link to JDBC 4.1 spec.